# How can I measure my connection for dropped packets, lag, ping times, jitter, etc?

Tags: networking

How can I adequately measure my connection health, testing for dropped packets and ping variance ("Jitter")?

I used to perform tests on pingtest.net (from the same creators of speedtest.net), but it requires Java.

What alternative tools or non-Java websites are available to test the health of your internet connection?

Comment: What's wrong with using Java?

Comment: [Java](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/04/chrome-starts-pushing-java-off-the-web-by-disabling-plugins/) [is](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2610229/java/java-s-security-dilemma--old--vulnerable-versions-won-t-go-away.html) [problematic.](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2030778/researchers-javas-security-problems-unlikely-to-be-resolved-soon.html)

Comment: That is a more than 2 year old article. In any case I think that pingtest.net is a safe site to visit. From personal experience I've had Java SDKs and JREs installed installed since JKD 1.0 (1996 or so) and never had any problems.

Comment: In addition, the loss of Chrome support for the JRE using NPAPI does not stop web applications using Java. [Java Web Start](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/launching_web_start_applications) is still supported. I'm sure websites like pingtest.net will eventually support Java Web Start.

Comment: It has been a pain in the ass every time I've used it and I'd rather not have it installed at all. PingTest.net might be safe, but some other site I end up on might not be. Honestly as a developer and an end-user, I'm ready for Java to go the way of Flash and just die out. It won't happen, but I'm hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

A fast in-browser test is offered by [DSL Reports](http://www.dslreports.com/tools/pingtest)

Here is their description for the test:

> Test how well your connection can reach a globally distributed set of servers. All servers are pinged twice a second (50 probes a second). The best and the current average difference from best latency is displayed. Every 30 seconds, the quality of the connection is graded from A+ to F. Any servers that are unreachable are highlighted.
>
> If there is local congestion or ISP problems then you may see volatile latency numbers and the radar graph will show an inner green area and an outer green boundary. A stable connection will show stable numbers, a good grade, and the radar graph will be a solid color with very little movement and activity.